# LibVLCSharp How to set the number of frames per second to play

Tags: libvlcsharp

I'm using LibVLCSharp to play a h264 video stream streamed from socekt, but it seems like I'm playing the wrong number of frames per second, causing the video to play wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use `--h264-fps=30` , for example for 30FPS, in the libvlc options.

See https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/